# How to over ride save button to get inline object in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am quite new.How to over ride save button to get inline object in django admin, just like in normal model save button in models.py file?

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
            task_update = Task.objects.get(id=self.task_id)
            if self.id is not None:
               task_update.is_assigned = False
               task_update.save()
       except Exception, e:
           print e
    super(TaskAssignment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of net I am able to answer my own question. Add this code in your admin.py and over ride save method models.py class.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class BookInline(object):
    model = Book
    form = BookForm
    fromset = BookFormSet
    form_layout = (
     ...
    )

class BookInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def save_new_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_instances = super(BookInlineFormSet,self).save_new_objects(commit)
        if commit:
            # create book for press
        return saved_instances

    def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_instances=super(BookInlineFormSet,self).save_existing_objects(commit)
        if commit:
            # update book for press
        return saved_instances
```